# ECONNRESET com postgres e sequelize no nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize-js

Bom estamos utilizando `nodejs v10.13.0` juntamente com ele o `sequelize 4.42.0` para fazer comunicação com nosso banco `postgres 9.2`, nosso servidor é na AZURE ele tem 8GB de HAM, 2 CPU e é CentOS 7. No banco estamos utilizando a abordagem de 2 `schemas`, e na verdade porá vir mais, pensamos que possivelmente poderia ser um problema isso, porém não temos a certeza disso. Assim estamos tendo vários problemas de conexão, em alguns momentos e em algumas `querys` o `sequelize` informar um erro no log.

> (node:22240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: read ECONNRESET
>   warning.js:18
>       at Query.formatError (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:363:16)
>       at query.catch.err (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\query.js:86:18)
>       at tryCatcher (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:690:18)
>       at _drainQueueStep (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
>       at _drainQueue (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
>       at Async._drainQueues (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (c:\Users\ax10415\projetos\aperam.mes.tubos\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
>       at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
>   (node:22240) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 10)

Ja tentamos fazer algumas atualizações para no arquivo de configuração segundo o site [PGTune](https://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/#/)

```
# DB Version: 9.2
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: web
# Total Memory (RAM): 8 GB
# CPUs num: 2
# Data Storage: ssd

max_connections = 200
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 10485kB
checkpoint_segments = 32
```

Quando fizemos estás configurações o primeiro problema interessante aconteceu, ele reclamou do `kernel shmmax` estudando encontramos que o próprio `PGTune` informa que precisamos mudar então aplicamos as mudanças no arquivo `/etc/sysctl.conf` adicionando as linhas

```
kernel.shmmax=4294967296
kernel.shmall=1048576
```

Além disso tentamos aumentar a capacidade do servidor de 4GB para 8GB porém também não tivemos sucesso algum. Enfim não estamos entendendo qual é o problema, a mensagem de erro não é clara (ao menos para mim).

Comment: coloca o codigo q ta lancando o erro dentro de um try catch e imprime o err no catch pra ver o q ta dando igual ele ta dizendo

Comment: Na verdade da o mesmo erro que está na pergunta. Aconteceu algo engraçado, anteriormente 4 desenvolvedores estavam conectados na mesma base porém fazendo esta conexão estava dando o econreset, depois disso passamos a trabalhar localmente, e tudo está estabilizado, não estamos tendo problemas referente a isso mais, entretendo não conseguimos depurar o erro, se alguém possuir alguma solução eminente ainda sim pode adicionar.

Comment: vcs tem certeza que estao com acesso a base externa sem ser a local? pode ser problema de permissao. Estao usando alguma vpn no banco?